# Style triggers in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, binding, triggers, coding-style

I want to use the style triggers in Windows Phone 7 to change the source of an image depending a boolean variable.

I Wann do something like this :

```
<Image Source="/Century21;component/Images/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png" Name="IconButtonSelection">
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Century21;component/Images/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Century21;component/Images/appbar.check.rest.png"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Is it possible to use datatrigger with windows phone 7 ?
What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight 3 (on which the WP7 framework is based) doesn't support style triggers. You could apply a trigger to the `Image` element itself instead of the style, but you'd need to get hold of an implementation of `DataTrigger` from somewhere. You can probably pull it out of the Blend SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just databind the imagesource and update that based on (or rather than) `IsSelected`?

Comment: Ok, Good idea, i just want to seprare view and model correctly, but i think i can't :s 
Thanks for the trick