# Binding c# xaml element depending on value

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have `<TextBlock Text="{Binding TexT}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>`
Also have {Binding Read_State} (bool Read_State)
How I can change color of TextBlock to blue if Read_State==false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a DataTrigger in a style for your TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock ...>
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Read_State}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

I would rename your PhoneTextNormalStyle to PhoneTextStyle and add the trigger to that style which would then handle both (or all states if there are more conditions).

Comment: Style class has no Triggers property.I'm using Windows Phone SDK(beta 2)

Comment: Apologize, I didn't notice the wp7 tag; this is a related question and maybe the accepted answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647557/style-triggers-in-windows-phone-7