# wp7 c# implement trigger on control template

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I'm building a small wp7 application in which I have a star user control, when the star is clicked its color changes.
Here's the code I've got:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="starTemplate"  TargetType="ToggleButton">
             <Viewbox>
                 <Path Name="star" Fill="Gray" Data="F1 M 145.637,174.227L 127.619,110.39L 180.809,70.7577L 114.528,68.1664L 93.2725,5.33333L 70.3262,67.569L 4,68.3681L 56.0988,109.423L 36.3629,172.75L 91.508,135.888L 145.637,174.227 Z"/>
              </Viewbox>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                     <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                   </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Tag="1" Cursor="Hand" Template="{StaticResource starTemplate}" Click="RatingButtonClickEventHandler"/>
```

the problem is that its giving me an error on the trigger:

```
The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'ControlTemplate'
```

I've read in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647557/style-triggers-in-windows-phone-7) that silverlight 3 doesn't support style triggers and that I have to implement DataTrigger somewhere. The question is How?