# Use DataTemplate.Triggers in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, datatrigger

I am using an ItemsControl in WP application to show a list of objects ( bind an observable collection to this list).
In WPF we can update the UI if any object properties is updated , but when it comes to WP8 , how can i do the same?  Below is the syntax used in WPF , but in WP8 it shows Triggers not found

```
       <ItemsControl> 
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate> 
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers> 

                </DataTemplate.Triggers> 
                </DataTemplate> 
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
        </ItemsControl>
```

how can i update UI in WP8 ? What i am planning to do is based on the property of an Object set the visibility of a button in the Items.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a Trigger. How about using a converter (implementing IValueConverter) to set the visibility based on the property. So your xaml would look like:

```
<button visibility="{binding YourObjectProperty, Converter={staticresource YourVisibilityConvert}}  ... />
```

Then whenever the propertychanged event is fired for the property, the ui will update visibility based on the value returned by the converter.

Comment: Is there any way of adding Triggers on WP8 elements loaded from an observable collection

Comment: As far as I know, it's not something available for windows phone and converters seem to be the best compromise. You can find a pretty good visibility converter here: http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/super-duper-all-in-one-visibilityconverter-for-wpdev/

Comment: you could try for behaviors [Behavior implementation](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx)  [Related Question in stact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647557/style-triggers-in-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to set behavior using Expression blend

```
xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" x:Class="XXX_XXXX"

<Image Source="/Assets/Images/Tick.png"
                   Stretch="None"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Change}" Value="False">
                        <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source">
                            <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>

                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/Images/Close.png"/>
                            </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </ec:DataTrigger>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>
```

[Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134801(v=expression.40).aspx)